# Interface is messed up after installing several plugins | Signal only works in main thread - Spyder report

Tags: python, spyder

I'm trying to install several `plug-in`s in **Spyder** IDE, such as:

> - `unit test`
> - `notebook`
> - `line profiler`
> - `spyder-terminal`
> - `memory-profiler`
> - `spyder-report`

But unfortunately, I've got some serious problem. The installation was good, though I couldn't install `spyder-vim` and `conda-manager` plug-in for some unknown reason.

But the thing was horrible after launching the IDE. It's just broken somehow and not responding. Mouse unclickable. The interface was totally messed up.

[image]

After removal of these plug-ins, I again manually installed those plug-ins and tried to figure it out which plug-in caused this.

This time I only installed

> `unit test` `spyder-report` `notebook` `terminal`

and now after launching, I saw interface was a little bit finer than before and discovered some problem in the `spyder-report` plug-in. While rendering `report to HTML` it showed the following error:

> `signal only works in main thread`

[image]

I'm not sure whether I'll try other plug-in, but everything is pretty OK now except the `spyder-report` plug-in. I googled it for a day, but I found no effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say which version of Spyder and Python you installed, nor which operating system you are using. So, using Debian unstable and Python 3.6.5, I installed:

- `spyder3`, 3.2.6
- `spyder-common`, 3.2.6
- `python3-spyder`, 3.2.6
- `python3-spyder-memory-profiler`, 0.1.2
- `python3-spyder-line-profiler`, 0.1.1
- `python3-spyder-reports`, 0.1.1
- `python3-spyder-unittest`, 0.3.0

as well as all of their dependencies. After that, I started `spyder3` without any problems (except that I have to use the Spyder 2 icon theme, because it can't find the Spyder 3 icons). The Reports tab works fine, no "Signal only..." error.

The problem with `spyder-vim` seems to be that no actual release has been made yet, so `pip3 install spyder-vim` doesn't find anything.

Last, I added the terminal plugin with `pip3 install spyder-terminal`.

Again, after that all is working fine.

Comment: BTW, `conda-manager` installs for me, but Spyder doesn't seem to find it :( Not sure why yet.

Comment: If you see the given picture clearly, you will get it's Windows OS ( first picture , upper right corner ) and it's Python 3.6 ( first picture upper left corner ). And which i didn't mention is version of Spyder IDE , which is 3.2.8.

Comment: Very true, sorry for missing that! So which versions of the plugins are you using, and how did you install them?

Comment: I just followed their instruction on github , and so it might be the last update version.