# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_explain'

Tags: tensorflow, installation, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to install `tf-explain` .So after installing anaconda and tensorflow now I am trying to install `tf-explain` So in order I have used :

```
pip install tf-explain
and 
pip3 install tf-explain
```

it's result:

```
Alt@mx:~
$ pip install tf-explain
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: tf-explain in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.3.0)
Alt@mx:~
$ pip3 install tf-explain
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: tf-explain in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.3.0)
Alt@mx:~
```

But when in spyder when I am trying to import this:

```
from tf_explain.callbacks.activations_visualization import ActivationsVisualizationCallback
```

I got this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_explain'
```

I am using conda base environment.

[image]

Comment: What's your OS? What's your `tf` version? Have you installed `opencv`?

Comment: I am using linux and `print(tf.__version__) : 2.2.0` and yes opencv is installed @M.Innat

Comment: print(cv2.__version__) 4.2.0 @M.Innat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested on Windows and Linux (colab) os and it works.

```
!pip install opencv-python
!pip install tensorflow

import cv2                  
import tensorflow as tf 

tf.__version__, cv2.__version__
('2.4.1', '4.1.2')

!pip install tf-explain
Collecting tf-explain
Downloading 
Installing collected packages: tf-explain
Successfully installed tf-explain-0.3.0

from tf_explain.utils.display import filter_display
from tf_explain.callbacks.activations_visualization import ActivationsVisualizationCallback
```

Your issue probably involves a [spyder environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60161513/9215780) setup.

Comment: If you have a virtual environment, you need to ensure that you are in the right environment.

Comment: As your question more about `tf_explain`, I would suggest using `jupyter-lab/notebook` or `vscode` like stuff and avoid spyder, here is [one cause.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50555566/9215780)

Comment: When I install `!pip install tf-explain` it is installing in this path `Requirement already satisfied: tf-explain in ./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.3.0)
Collecting install` mean `/python3.7/` but spyder environment is `python 3.8.3 @M.Innat

Comment: So, you have a different version of python. Do you have a different conda environment with a different python versions? or you for some reason install a different versions of python in one environment?

Comment: I created environment with python 3.7 and after installing tf and cv2 in new environment finally `tf_explain` imported successfully. The keyword was creating environment with `python3.7` @M.Innat